# Ensure rewrite-rule is used

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have created a simple rewrite URL like this:

```
RewriteRule ^messages$ /messages.php [L]
```

How do I force the user to use /messages and not /messages.php? I.e., if user queries messages.php, he'll be 301 redirected to /messages.

I have a long list of rewrite rules, like the one above.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^messages$ /messages.php [L]
RewriteRule ^events$ /events.php [L]
RewriteRule ^cv$ /cv.php [L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ratings$ /ratings.php [L]
RewriteRule ^newsfeed$ /newsfeed.php [L]
RewriteRule ^logout$ /logout.php [L]
RewriteRule ^profile$ /profile.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ranking$ /rank.php [L]
RewriteRule ^find-study$ /search.php [L]
RewriteRule ^search/$ /search.php [L]
RewriteRule ^search$ /search.php [L]
RewriteRule ^invite-friends$ /invite-friends.php [L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1&programme=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^student-requests$ /student-requests.php [L]

# Q&A

    # view question
        RewriteRule ^question(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]*))?)?/?$ /question.php?id=$1&permalink=$2 [L]
        RewriteRule ^question/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /question.php?id=$1&permalink=$2&answer=$3 [L]

    # manage question
        RewriteRule ^ask(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]*))?)?/?$ /manageQuestion.php?tag_id=$1&tag_type=$2 [L]
        RewriteRule ^ask/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /manageQuestion.php?tag_id=$1&tag_type=$2&tag_name=$3 [L]

        RewriteRule ^editquestion(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]*))?)?/?$ /manageQuestion.php?id=$1&second=$2 [L]

    # questions
        RewriteRule ^questions$ /questions.php [L]
        RewriteRule ^questions/([^/]*)$ /questions.php?first=$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^questions/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /questions.php?first=$1&second=$2 [L]
        RewriteRule ^questions/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /questions.php?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3 [L]
        RewriteRule ^questions/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /questions.php?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3&fourth=$4 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

When trying to solve this problem you probably encountered the problem of infinite loops. One way to prevent this is to use `%{THE_REQUEST}`, since this variable doesn't change on a rewrite. Therefore, if you use the following rule, it will change every url ending on `.php` to an url without it:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /(messages|events|cv|ratings|etc)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ %2 [R,L]
```

After testing that the rule works correctly, change `[R,L]` to `[R=301,L]` to make the redirect permanent. Doing this before everything works correctly makes testing a pain.

Edit: Instead of using `(.*)` you could use `/(page1|page2|page3)` for all the simple redirects. For each of the more complex ones you probably need to have a single redirect each in the form of:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /questions\.php\?id=([^&]+)&permalink=([^&]+)&answer=([^&]+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ questions/%2/%3/%4 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I do not, however, want every page to redirect. Is there a smarter way? I have updated my original answer, with a preview of how my redirect rules looks.

Comment: I have updated my answer; you'll probably not get it any smarter than this.